# connecting different capacity batteries in paralell

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, parallel

I have 12 li-ion batteries but in different capacities. Half of them is 2000 mAh and half of them is 6000 mAh.

What happen if I parallel them?

Comment: How many times have you seen plastic battery compartment modules that accomodate different sized batteries?

Comment: yeah but i want to know scientifically what happen ?

Comment: my battery size is equal but the capacity is different

Comment: The one with lesser mAh will get discharged quicker than the other. The stronger one then starts charging the other after that. Undesirable scenario.

Comment: You have to balance them before paralleling them, the cells must be matched. If you want to know what happens with unmatched cells? Fires happen.

Comment: @laptop2d if you hold your battery voltage between 3.5 to 4.2 , don't worry , no fires happen

Comment: Until all the current goes through one cell...

Answer (score 1):

It's not nice.

You have 12 cells, all at 4.2V, and you're drawing 10 out of the pack. They start out equal, and all provide 1/12th of current. As the lower capacity ones discharge, they drop their voltage faster than the higher capacity ones, and so start contributing less current. This pretty much self balances if all the cells are identical other than capacity.

This never happens because no two cells are identical, if they are different capacities they are even more different, especially with their voltage discharge curves and internal impedance and so will perform very differently.

In the real world, the different cells output different currents, probably causing significantly different "off-state" voltages, which would cause the higher capacity ones to charge up the lower capacity ones in some uncontrolled way.

Comment: Some active load-balancing circuitry can get around the problem, but it makes things a lot more complicated. Then again, working safely with lithium-ion batteries is always complicated.